# How to retrieve the json_encode values to user side

Tags: php

My table name is tinfo and columnname is classconducted. column conducted  class contains like this.

```
{"segment":["Class I-V Tuition","Class VI-VIII Tuition","Class IX-X Tuition"],"Board":["cbse","cse/Ise","State"],"classFiveSubject":["allsubject","science"],"classeightboard":["cbse","cse/Ise"],"classeightsubject":null,"classTenthboard":["cbse","cse/Ise"],"classTenthsubject":null,"engineering":null}
```

I want output should look like this:

```
classconducted.
segment:Class I-V Tuition
Board:CBSE,STATE
classFiveSubject:AllSubject,Maths,Science

segment:Class VI-VIII Tuition
Board:CBSE, STATE
classEightSUbject:AllSubject,Maths,Science .

And my index having engineering is null here I don't want  to show the null values, can any one guide me. what I have write in query.
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from tinfo");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo $row['classconducted'];
}
?>
```

Comment: this value is saved in that particular field? most likely a JSON string, try to decode it, and loop it.

Comment: Yes .Can you guide me how to that .I am not sure . if you see my output sample you can understand this. here each array of [0] has the output of first segment segment:Class I-V Tuition
Board:CBSE,STATE
classFiveSubject:AllSubject,Maths,Science

Comment: check out the answer below, that should give the the idea how to tackle this thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PHP function called `json_decode()` [see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Basically if you run the json string through this function it will convert it to a PHP variable i.e. if the json string is an object you get a PHP object and if its a json array you get a PHP array ... etc

So take your json string and pass it through json_decode() and you will get

```
$in = '{"segment":["Class I-V Tuition","Class VI-VIII Tuition","Class IX-X Tuition"],"Board":["cbse","cse/Ise","State"],"classFiveSubject":["allsubject","science"],"classeightboard":["cbse","cse/Ise"],"classeightsubject":null,"classTenthboard":["cbse","cse/Ise"],"classTenthsubject":null,"engineering":null}';

print_r( json_decode($in) );
```

Output =

```
stdClass Object
(
    [segment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Class I-V Tuition
            [1] => Class VI-VIII Tuition
            [2] => Class IX-X Tuition
        )

    [Board] => Array
        (
            [0] => cbse
            [1] => cse/Ise
            [2] => State
        )

    [classFiveSubject] => Array
        (
            [0] => allsubject
            [1] => science
        )

    [classeightboard] => Array
        (
            [0] => cbse
            [1] => cse/Ise
        )

    [classeightsubject] =>
    [classTenthboard] => Array
        (
            [0] => cbse
            [1] => cse/Ise
        )

    [classTenthsubject] =>
    [engineering] =>
)
```

Now you should be able to process it using standard PHP code.

Comment: It's great thanks  Again How to loop through as I want the output I have listed in my question . For first output segment[0], Board[0][1][2] calssFiveSubject[0][1]  values with having their index like Board,classFiveSubject..For second outp segment[1] classEightboard[0][1]. Here I understood the work concept. how to make it foreach. and one morething i don't want to know null values like engineering

Comment: I didn't realise you wanted to hire someone to code this project for you!

Comment: Sure I will improve my Technical stuff I am trying like this for($i=0; $i<count($in); $i++)
{
if($in[$i]=="Class I-V Tuition")
{
echo $in[$i];
}  some lack of inexperience.I am individual person doing marketing,developing,webhosting,I have one resource like You.or stackteam If I have sit consistent I will make the task. can make it for me . Definitely . I will improve my level

Comment: As the required output you specify does not seem to match the data, I am unsure how to go any further with a complete solution

Comment: Thanks RiggFolly .shall I get atleast like this is it enough for me.Really thanks for support.It's ok  Board:CBSE,STATE
classFiveSubject:AllSubject,Maths,Science
Board:CBSE, STATE
classEightSUbject:AllSubject,Maths,Science .